# Protobuf Build Protoc select all .proto files in a directory

Tags: sh, protoc, grpc-web

I have the following `.sh` file that I run to build my protos.

```
mkdir -p ./src/gen

protoc -I=../protos/                                       \
       ../protos/common/*.proto                            \
       ../protos/service/protos/*.proto                    \
       ../protos/ui/*.proto                                \
       ../protos/*.proto                                   \
       --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/gen     \
       --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext:./src/gen
```

It works great, however, my team might add other directories to the `protos` directory that this file doesn't see.

Is there a way for me to update this script to get all `.proto` files in the `protos` directory?

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
mkdir -p ./src/gen

protoc -I=../protos/**/*.proto                                             \
       --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/gen                     \
       --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext:./src/gen
```

I'm sure it's just some syntax issue, but I'm not sure how to do it.

**EDIT:**

I've implemented something to make my generators more flexible, but it's still messy:

```
mkdir -p ./src/gen

protoc -I=../protos/                                   \
       ../protos/*.proto                               \
       ../protos/**/*.proto                            \
       ../protos/**/**/*.proto                         \
       ../protos/**/**/**/*.proto                      \
       ../protos/**/**/**/**/*.proto                   \
       --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/gen \
       --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext:./src/gen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your script will pass the complete path for every file, it should be enough to add the `protos/` folder with `-I=../protos`. The code below works fine for me, with multiple proto files in different subfolders.

```sh
$ tree ../protos
../protos
├── a
│   └── a.proto
└── b
    ├── b.proto
    └── c
        └── c.proto

$ protoc \
  -I=../protos \
  ../protos/**/*.proto \
  --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./src/gen

$ tree src/gen
src/gen
├── a
│   └── a_pb.js
└── b
    ├── b_pb.js
    └── c
        └── c_pb.js

3 directories, 3 files
```

In your original question, you may just have mixed up `../protos/*/**.proto` with `../protos/**/*.proto`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, when I do that it seems to just give me protos for everything 1 directory deep. I miss out on the root directory and the 2+ deep directories.

Comment: Seems like you use a shell where `**` and `*` are identical. Try ZSH or bash with `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: I currently run `bash ./gen-protos.sh`, what command should I run in order to do this where it would for my dev environment (so that my colleagues won't need to do any additional setup).

Comment: Adding `shopt -s globstar` to the script itself could work.

Comment: What about running `zsh ./gen-protos.sh`?